# Regular Expression Extracting country name from a string

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a bunch of strings that I want to extract the country name from it.

```
http://api.com/Location_Republic_of_the_Congo_1000
http://api.com/Location_US_994
```

It seems like I need the Regexp that extract the string between the FIRST '*' and the LAST '*' sign. For the example above, I want to get this:

```
Republic_of_the_Congo
US
```

I wrote this: `REGEXP_EXTRACT([Country], '(?<=_)(?s)(.*$)' )` but it does not work like I want it to.

I also want to extract 'Cov_Death' from ':RecordedCase_Armenia_558_2_1_2020_Cov_Death'. String between LAST TWO '_' sign.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Country], '_(.*)_')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCOdcD/1)

Here,

- `_` - an underscore
- `(.*)` - Capturing group #1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (due to the `*` greedy quantifier)
- `_` - an underscore

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you extract this below?
FROM this ':RecordedCase_Armenia_558_3_20_2020_Cov_Death', I want to extract

'Cov_Death' and 'Death' separately. I want to extract the string between LAST TWO '_' sign

Comment: @Eren If my solution solved your problem please consider upvoting/accepting. Regarding the comment, it is a separate issue. 2 issues in fact. To get `Cov_Death` use `_([^_]+_[^_]+)$`, to get `Death`, use `_([^_]+)$`.